# How to build dynamic url for http connector in Clover ETL

Tags: clover, cloveretl

How to build http dynamic url in http connector to map values from sql source in CloverDX? For now I have dbread component with selected one column (list of TAXIDs) in table which should be my dynamic attribute/parameter for url...
I need to build url with Path Parameter - TAXID and Query Parameter — getdate(today)

Something like:
`GET baseurl/api/search/taxid/{taxid}?date={getdate(today)}`

Answer (score 0):

Use 'Input Mapping' property of HTTPConnector where you can build URL manually (in $out.0.URL = 'baseurl/api/search/taxid/' + $in.0. taxid + '?date='+ date2str(today(),'yyyy_Mm....')

OR
use 'Add input fields as parameters', provide records with field 'taxid' and 'date' (with prefilled value of date) and query will be build automatically, on the fly with provided values in mentioned fields.